# Merge columns with have \n

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns

ex)

```
   C1  C2  C3  C4  C5  C6
0  A   B   nan C   A   nan
1  B   C   D   nan B   nan
2  D   E   F   nan C   nan
3  nan nan A   nan nan B
```

I'm merging columns, but I want to give '\n\n' in the merging process.

so output what I want

```
   C
0  A  

   B  

   C

   A
1  B  

   C  

   D

   B
2  D  

   E  

   F

   C
3. A

   B
```

I want 'nan' to drop.

I tried

```
df['merge'] = df['C1'].map(str) + '\n\n' + tt['C2'].map(str) + '\n\n' + tt['C3'].map(str) + '\n\n' + df['C4'].map(str)
```

However, this includes all nan values.

thank you for reading.

Comment: Why don't you replace the NAN with empty string before merging?

Comment: This is an example data sample,
The actual number of columns is different for each row!

I'll edit the data sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for Series, misisng values are removed, so you can aggregate `join`:

```
df['merge'] = df.stack().groupby(level=0).agg('\n\n'.join)
#for filter only C columns
df['merge'] = df.filter(like='C').stack().groupby(level=0).agg('\n\n'.join)
```

Or remove missing values by join per rows by [`Series.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dropna.html):

```
df['merge'] = df.apply(lambda x: '\n\n'.join(x.dropna()), axis=1)
#for filter only C columns
df['merge'] = df.filter(like='C').apply(lambda x: '\n\n'.join(x.dropna()), axis=1)
```

---

```
print (df)
    C1   C2   C3   C4   C5   C6             merge
0    A    B  NaN    C    A  NaN  A\n\nB\n\nC\n\nA
1    B    C    D  NaN    B  NaN  B\n\nC\n\nD\n\nB
2    D    E    F  NaN    C  NaN  D\n\nE\n\nF\n\nC
3  NaN  NaN    A  NaN  NaN    B            A\n\nB
```